# How to serialize an object in windows phone 7

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, javascriptserializer

How to convert an object to JSON data in windows phone. In web application I have used following code

```
 JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 string stringData = serializer.Serialize(object);
```

I want to get the same output as that of the above code in windows phone 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JavaScriptSerializer` is not supported on Windows Phone. An alternative is to use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) (you can add it via NuGet).

The code will then look like this:

```
string stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
```

Comment: Is there any other solution than using JSON.NET??

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializer is another option (in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll)

Answer (score 0):

firrst you need to download Newtonsoft.Json dll for parse web serevice

Just follow bellow step

**Step1:** Add Service References by right click on add References.

**Step2:** Now put your web service link on Service References and press go button, And also add Namespace of service Reference 
[image]

**Step3:** Now add using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` name space in your .cs file

**Step4:** Now add bellow code in your cs file

```
 WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient ws = new WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient();
ws.ContactUsJSONCompleted += ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted;
ws.ContactUsJSONAsync(txtContactUsName.Text, txtContactUsPhone.Text, txtContactUsEmail.Text, txtContactUsComment.Text);
```

**step6:** now genrate your resopnce method

```
 void ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted(object sender, dynamic e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(LogIn.NetworkBusyMsg, LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                string Result = e.Result;
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(Result);
                string ResultCode = (string)obj["ResultCode"];
                string ResponceMessage = (string)obj["ResponseMessage"];

                if (ResultCode == "1")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Thank you for your message. We'll get back to you soon.", LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help you.

If any query than comment here.I wll help you